# How to pass variables between classes in PHP without extending

Tags: php, oop, class, variables, extend

So, I've got my setup like this:

```
class System extends mysqli{

    function __construct(){
         //user variables such as $this->username are returned here
    }

}

$sys = new System();

class Design{

    function setting(){
        echo $sys->username;
    }

}

$design = new Design();
```

Yet the Design class doesn't echo the username. I can echo the username outside of the Design class, but not inside the design class. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone else's answer is fine, but you can inject the dependency on system very nicely:

```
class Design{

    private $sys;

    public function __construct(System $sys) {
       $this->sys = $sys;
    }

    function setting(){
        echo $this->sys->username;
    }
}
$sys = new System;
$design = new Design($sys);
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still not working for me. I get none of the variables, and the variables inside the System class are set to public.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've found the problem. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Your `Design` class has no access to the `$sys` variable.

You have to do something like this:

```
class System extends mysqli{

    function __construct(){
         //user variables such as $this->username are returned here
    }

}

class Design{

    private $sys;

    function __construct(){
        $this->sys = new System();
    }

    function setting(){
        echo $this->sys->username;
    }

}

$design = new Design();
```

Comment: This is initially what I had tried and it didn't work for some odd reason.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `$sys` isn't in the scope of the Design class.

```
function setting(){
    $sys = new System();
    $sys->username;
}
```

should work, assuming that `username` is public.

Comment: +1 I do not think that your answer is as bad as using global variables. I upvote it so it is not treated as being of the same value.